# VisualStyleRenderer returns error for menu item

Tags: c#, visual-styles

The code

```
var renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Menu.Item.Normal);
```

returns the following message

> Given combination of Class, Part, and State is not defined by the
>   current visual style.

on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Does anybody know why and how I can work around this?

Comment: I repro, stricter error checking I'm guessing.  None of the parts whose name end in "TMSCHEMA" are permitted.  Whatever they mean, I'd guess the .NET programmer didn't know either.  Consider new VisualStyleRenderer("MENU", 8, 1) instead to get a "BarItem".

Comment: I'm not sure what part 8 is. If I try BarItem then identifier is 3. Either way it's not the right styling exactly - the text is not rendered the same. Is there some look up list of codes somewhere?

Comment: Look in the vsstyle.h Windows SDK header file for part and state numbers.

Comment: Ah I see now where the 8 is from :) I tried using MENU_POPUPBACKGROUND  and am having some luck, but the text is still not 100%. I logged a .NET Framework bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/921798/visualstylerenderer-visualstyleelement-menu-item-normal-returns-not-supported-always so let's see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Ok so with [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)'s  help I had a look at the vsstyle.h file (found a copy [here](http://www.ookii.org/misc/vsstyle.h)) and have been using those constants.

If you look at the enum MENUPARTS, I find the "MENU" class path works with all the parts except the ones with *_TMSCHEMA in the name (which is what the structures in the VisualStyleElement.Menu list are mapped to)

So, I ended up using the MENU_POPUPITEM and siblings parts and they seem to work well.

eg:

```
var renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer("MENU", (int)MENUPARTS.MENU_POPUPBACKGROUND, (int)POPUPCHECKBACKGROUNDSTATES.MCB_NORMAL);
renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, r);

renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer("MENU", (int)MENUPARTS.MENU_POPUPGUTTER, 0);
renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, 24, e.Bounds.Height));
```

I hope this helps someone.

---

IE: It seems as if the VisualStyleRenderer.GetMargins method is broken because if I do this

```
protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
   var renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer("MENU", (int)MENUPARTS.MENU_POPUPITEM, (int)POPUPITEMSTATES.MPI_HOT);
   var m = renderer.GetMargins(e.Graphics, MarginProperty.SizingMargins);
   // etc...
}
```

I always get a memory corrupted error.